# Car stereo is always on when engine is on

Tags: electrical, toyota, audio, power, matrix

I have a 2011 Toyota Matrix XRS. When I turn the engine on, the screen for the stereo doesn't light up, and the power/volume button doesn't work - can't turn it off, and can't lower the volume. Super annoying as the volume is fairly high and it's tuned to a college radio station that is not what I want to be hearing about 80% of the time.

Is there a way to "reboot" the stereo? Seems to me like the stereo's software is in a bad state.

Comment: Have you checked the msnual or asked the Dealer for a reset ?

Comment: I'll check the manual later. Wanted to avoid going to the dealer if possible

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You could try pulling [fuse #25 on the underhood fuse panel](https://www.autogenius.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/toyota-matrix-mk2-fuse-box-engine-compartment.jpg) and leaving it out for a few minutes. It is the fuse for the radio. There is a separate fuse for the amp, but you shouldn't need to worry about that.

Comment: @Paulster2 That's the answer I would have posted, but your comment is much more concise and provides specifics. Isn't that an answer rather than a comment?